# How I can get back in singly linked list?

Tags: singly-linked-list

I have a singly linked list. From each node in the list, I can get to the next element. Is it possible instead to get to the previous element? Note that I cannot use a doubly linked list because of memory constraints.

Comment: Save what it is before you get the next....

Comment: That's not what _singly_ means.

Comment: You might want to consider using a doubly-linked list.

Comment: I have no memory for doubly linked link i have to use singly ! this is my question how to make it have to have way

Comment: The whole point of single linked list is they only scan one way! There might be a sneaky pete solution to your problem, but teher cannot be a generic one, so more info needed. Do you need previous.previous etc?

Comment: for example I have a list with a int numbers then the memory for the links will be more than actual element. I know that the idea of singly linked list is that cannot move back but I need it and there is way to make it for sure. Yes Tony I need the previous.previous

Comment: Take your linked list read it in into an array / List<int> type chap and throw the now proven utterly useless single linked list away.

Comment: I changed the wording in your question to make it more readable. Please read it and make sure it still means what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a singly linked list, then one way to approach this is to traverse the list again until you find the prior item. You will know when you are at the prior item when its `Next` field is equal to the current item.

Pseudo C code:

```
Node* GetPreviousNode(Node* currentNode)
{
    Node* iteratorNode = GetHeadNode();
    while (iteratorNode != NULL)
    {
        if (iteratorNode->Next == currentNode)
            return iteratorNode;

        iteratorNode = iteratorNode->Next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to use a double-linked-list where you have a pointer to the previous and next elements. A single linked list simply points to the next element and doesn't keep track off previous elements.

Try this:
http://en.literateprograms.org/Doubly_linked_list_(Java)

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 different methods for traversing a singly linked list both ways.

Method 1: The link field (of the structure) is actually a 'difference' field.  The link is computed
as the address of the next item minus the address of the previous item, therefore ...

next = address of the previous item + link of the current item.
  prev = address of the next item - link of the current item.

If you can do arithmetic with pointers, you will be in business.  If not, you will have to use a union (in C++) or use method 2.  See: Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs by Niklaus Wirth - Prentice-Hall
1976 - page 19.

Method 2: The link field is the 'exclusive or' (^) of the address of the previous item with the address
of the next item.  Exclusive or  is an inverse of itself, therefore ...

next = address of the previous item ^ link of the current item.
  prev = address of the next item     ^ link of the current item.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a node that you are sure of, is before the given node in a singly linked list, then you can make a function:-

```
    struct node* prev(struct node* before, struct student_detail* current)
    {
        struct student_detail* temp = before;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            if(temp->next == current)
            {
                return temp;
            }

            temp = temp-> next;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

and use it as in

```
    example_node = prev(before, example_node);
```

If you have head, you can always use that as the prev node.

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically go back, it generally beats the whole concept behind a singly linked list and it's more trouble than necessary but if you have to, here's how to implement it in C, assuming of course, you already declared your Node struct:-

```
Node* go_back(Node* head, Node* current_node){
   //Traverse the linked list until we discover the next node
   //in our traversal points to our current node
   Node* previous_node = head;
   while(previous_node->next != NULL){
       if(previous_node->next == current_node)
           return previous_node->next; //found previous node
       previous_node = previous_node->next;
   } 
   return previous_node //we found nothing, give up
}
```